# Hi, Here I am trying to connect the front end and the back end of my dapp by using React and I faced this error

Tags: java, reactjs, frontend, backend, blockchain

Here i code `App.js` as below and i want only 2 function from my smart contract (mystring, evolution) to be calling in the front end i want when press on button (sequence id) i get 4 strings
and when press on button (offspring) i get 8 strings
please can any one help me because i am very beginner in react.js and blockchain environment

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import Lock from "./artifacts/contracts/Lock.sol/Lock.json";
import "./App.css";
//import { data } from 'autoprefixer';
const lockAddress = "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3";

function App() {
  const [locking, setLockingValue] = useState("");

  async function InputSequence() {
    if (typeof window.ethereum != "undefined") {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(lockAddress, Lock.abi, provider);
      try {
        const data = await contract.MyString();
        setLockingValue(data);
        console.log("data:", data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.Console.log("ERROR:", err);
      }
    }
  }
  async function evolution(value) {
    if (!value) return;
    if (!typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
      await requestAccount();
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(lockAddress, Lock.abi, signer);
      const transaction = await contract.evolution(value);
      await transaction.wait();
      InputSequence();
      //this.setState({myResult:data});
    }
  }

  async function requestAccount() {
    await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
  }
  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    await evolution(event.target.lockingInput.value);
    setLockingValue(event.target.lockingInput.value);
    event.target.lockingInput.value = "";
  }
  return (
    <div className="w-full max-w-lg container">
      <div className="shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 mt-4" />
      <div className="text-gray-600 font-bold text-lg mb-2">
        SONR Ethereum Dapp
      </div>
      <div className="w-full border-4 p-2 mb-4 rounded border-gray-400">
        <div className="text-gray-600 font-bold text-md mb-2 ">
          Input sequence From Smart Contract
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
            {" "}
            sequence ID{" "}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="w-full border-4 p-2 mb-4 rounded border-gray-400">
        <div className="text-gray-600 font-bold text-md mb-2">
          output offsprings on Smart Contract
        </div>
        <form
          className="flex items-center justify-between"
          onSubmit={(Event) => handleSubmit(Event)}
        />
        <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow" />

        <button className="bg-red-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded ">
          {" "}
          offsprings{" "}
        </button>
        <form />
      </div>
      <div className="w-full border-4 p-2 mb-4 rounded border-gray-400 bg-gray-100">
        <div className="text-gray-600 font-bold text-md mb-2">
          Input sequence ID
        </div>
        <p>{locking}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but when i press on the button sequence id  & offspring nothing happens  as below nothing happens [image]

Answer (score 0):

your form enclose incorrectly, please try

```
<form
  className="flex items-center justify-between"
  onSubmit={(Event) => handleSubmit(Event)}
>
  <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow" />
  <button className="bg-red-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded " type="submit">
    offsprings
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Nothing happened, the situation remains the same